# Ubuntu 13.04 will not boot after install?

Tags: boot, nvidia

So i got Ubuntu 13.04 to install using my onboard video card but what i want is my nvidia geforce 8400 gs to be my main video card but when i turn it on in bios ubuntu will not boot.  Any ideas on how i can fix this problem? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We'd need more information about your problem, so we can help. What exactly happens when you try booting? Can you boot in fail-safe and try installing video drivers? (not sure if nouveau drivers are installed by default even if you was using other brand like Intel or AMD graphics at the time of the install. (In my humble opinion, seems like a xorg issue.)

*Hope i help in some way.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

Comment: haven't tried booting in fail safe, but definitely will try it otherwise when I normally boot it up and it goes to the purple screen right before you have to enter a passphrase for an encrypted hdd that's when it normally reboots and keeps looping as far as rebooting is concerned.  On the other hand Ubuntu boots very nice using my onboard VGA.  I have tried installing the Official Nvidia drivers for the card for ubuntu os or linux os and screwed up the resolution for my onboard when i go back to that to boot ubuntu since I can't with my PCI video card, even if they are installed.

Comment: I tried to get to were the os asks you how to boot and it reboots before that screen and just is a constant loop if i dont go back to using my onboard VGA.